# Kubernetes 5 minutes self healing deployments, how to config?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes Cluster (v.1.10) with 3 nodes.

When I shutdown one node, deployments are self healing (redeploying pods in deployments on healthy nodes) after 5 minutes.

5 minutes is a bit too much. Is there any solution to make it faster please ?

Comment: Please look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317682/kubernetes-node-shutdown-crash-recovery

Comment: Perfect ! thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kubernetes node shutdown/crash recovery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317682/kubernetes-node-shutdown-crash-recovery)